# cv2 cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) Returns 'inf'

Tags: python, opencv

I need to read the fps and frames_count from cv2.videocapture().
In the case of short videos (15 min) it works fine.
But the problem is when i'm reading a 50 min video or more

```
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)  # fps = inf
fc = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) # fc = -9223372036854775808
```

I found nothing on the internet. It's critical in my project :/

Comment: that is 0x8000_0000_0000_0000 or a float of -0.0. could be a bug, or an error. -- OpenCV is the wrong library. OpenCV is for *computer vision*, not for handling media files. use ffmpeg or something.

Comment: i'm reading these videos for a computervision project!

Comment: run `ffprobe -of json` show format and streams

Comment: thnx that helped